# Hadoop MultipleInputs, TextInputFormat with different separators

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

How do I easiest run multiple different mapper classes (using `MultipleInputs`), all using the same input format, but with different input separators?

MultipleInput allows you to add multiple mappers, each with their own inputformat:

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(Job job, Path path,
  Class<? extends InputFormat> inputFormatClass,
  Class<? extends Mapper> mapperClass)
```

The input separator in `TextInputFormat` input is configured using by setting a config key `textinputformat.record.delimiter` in the job configuration. Handy!

However, that means all mappers added using `MultipleInput.addInputPath(?, TextInputFormat.class, ?)` will have to share the same separator, as specified by the `textinputformat.record.delimiter` config key.

Is there any way to get around this, without having to compile separate inputformat classes (extending `TextInputFormat`) with a hardcoded separator for each mapper?

Answer (score 0):

If you need multi input format, then you can create your own input format just to modify the delimiter and use them for your input paths. You can [look](https://amalgjose.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/custom-text-input-format-record-delimiter-for-hadoop/) here.

Your InputFormat class will override the createRecordReader() with your required delimiter.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. It smells like an ugly hack, but I guess I'll have to create a bunch of `TextInputformat1`, `TextInputformat2` ... `TextInputformatN` classes, each reading a different config field for the delimiter. Oh well.